# Hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I have an hibernate mapping using the "class" tag representing a publisher object. One of the publisher field is a really big description (30k char max).  I'm using oracle varchar field which have a maximum of 4k char, so i'm force to split my description in 8 differents fields (i'm force to use varchar field type btw).  I wan't to hide this database complexity and only have 1 description field in my publisher object.

The only way i found so far is to have a "transit" object mapped in hibernate with the 8 description field that i could manually copy on the fly in the final publisher object with only 1 description.

Anyone got a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could employ Hibernate's custom UserTypes to "magically" combine the columns into a single value.

This section of some of the docs discusses how to combine two columns to create a custom currency class upon retrieving data from a table.  That might get you started.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom

I'm personally using this to load blobs from the database, and it works nicely and, once you get the UserType written and mapped into your database mappings, your code doesn't even "know" about the actual physical types in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Using 8 fields for a single value is really ugly, but anyway...

Hibernate use objects. And objects use encapsulation. Provide public `getDescription()` and `setDescription()` methods in your entity, and have those methods join/split the description from/to your 8, private, persistent fields:

```
public String getDescription() {
    return join(desc1, desc2, ..., desc8);
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    String[] s = split(description);
    desc1 = s[0];
    ...
    desc8 = s[7];
}
```